# how to add row by specific value

Tags: r

For example, I have a dataset called data, and the column names are date min max avg. The total number of rows is 366.

I want to add the each seven rows to get the total value of min. e.g. 1-7 8-14. How can I do this.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `mtcars %>% group_by(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 7) %>% summarise(carb = sum(carb))` (using `dplyr`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a grouping column which increments after every 7 days you may apply all the answers from [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)  .

Here's how you can do it in base R.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() - 365:0, min = rnorm(366), max = runif(366))
df$group <- ceiling(seq(nrow(df))/7)
aggregate(min~group, df, sum)

#   group        min
#1      1  3.1438325
#2      2 -0.3022263
#3      3 -1.0769539
#4      4 -3.2934430
#5      5  2.8419110
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on `{tidyverse}`, in particular using `{dplyr}` for the main operations and `{lubridate}` for formatting your dates.

First simulate some data - as you have not provided a reproducible dataset. I take the year 2020 which has 366 days ... obviously adapt this to your problem.
For the min, max, and average values (columns) , let's generate some random numbers. Again, adapt this to your needs.

```
library(dplyr)  # for general data frame crunching
library(lubridate) # to coerce date-time

data <- data.frame(
   date = seq(from = lubridate::ymd("2020-01-01")
              , to = lubridate::ymd("2020-12-31"), by = 1)
  , min = sample(x = 1:10, size = 366, replace = TRUE)
  , max = sample(x = 10:15, size = 366, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(avg = mean(min + max))
```

To group your data, inject a binning / grouping variable.
The following is a generic "every 7th row" based on the modulo operator.
If you want to group by weeks, etc. check out the `{lubridate}`  documentation. You can get some useful bits out of dates for this. Or insert any other binning you need.

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(bin = c(0, rep(1:(nrow(data)-1)%/%7)))
```

This yields:

```
> data
# A tibble: 366 x 5
# Groups:   bin [53]
   date         min   max   avg   bin
   <date>     <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01     2    11  18.2     0
 2 2020-01-02     6    14  18.2     0
 3 2020-01-03     7    13  18.2     0
 4 2020-01-04     6    15  18.2     0
 5 2020-01-05     3    10  18.2     0
 6 2020-01-06     5    12  18.2     0
 7 2020-01-07     5    12  18.2     0
 8 2020-01-08     7    13  18.2     1
 9 2020-01-09     8    11  18.2     1
10 2020-01-10     5    10  18.2     1
```

We can now `summarise` our grouped data.
For this you use the bin-variable to group your data, and then summarise to perform aggregations on these groups. Based on your question, the following sums the min-values. Put the function/summary you need:

```
data %>% 
   group_by(bin) %>% 
   summarise(tot_min = sum(min))
# A tibble: 53 x 2
     bin tot_min
   <dbl>   <int>
 1     0      34
 2     1      31
 3     2      35
 4     3      44
 5     4      40
 6     5      50
 7     6      46
 8     7      38
 9     8      33
10     9      21
# ... with 43 more rows
```

Assign the result to your liking or whatever type of output you need.
If you want to combine this with your original data dataframe, read up on `bind_rows()`.